# Facebook: Only column Name from table Place could not be written through .innerHTML

Tags: php, javascript, dom, facebook-fql

FQL statement has executed and array object has been passed to `$fqlResult` successfully.

However, I'm unable to write `name` into my `<span>` through `innerHTML`. Neither exceptions nor errors have occurred. Other columns from the table such as `latitude`, `longitude`, `page_id`, `checkin_count` **are able to write into respective `<span>` correctly**. Only `name` is giving me problem.

May I know what is preventing me from writing `name` into my `<span>`?

[FQL Place Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/place/)

**FQL Statement**

```
SELECT page_id,name,latitude,longitude,checkin_count 
FROM place 
WHERE distance(latitude, longitude,"1.2894680406278", "103.86311775635") < 200 
ORDER BY checkin_count DESC
```

Results from `print_r($fqlResult)` appears to be consistent with [results from Graph API Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/433576149993619/?fql=SELECT%20page_id,name,latitude,longitude,checkin_count%20FROM%20place%20WHERE%20distance%28latitude,%20longitude,%221.2894680406278%22,%20%22103.86311775635%22%29%20%3C%20200%20ORDER%20BY%20checkin_count%20DESC).

**HTML**

```
<b>Page Name: </b> <span id="fName"></span>
<b>Latitude: </b> <span id="fLatitude"></span>
<b>Longitude: </b> <span id="fLongitude"></span>
```

---

**Observation**

*JavaScript Setup 1* (Blockage)

```
document.getElementById('fName').innerHTML = <?=$fqlResult[0]['name']?>;
document.getElementById('fLatitude').innerHTML = <?=$fqlResult[0]['latitude']?>;
document.getElementById('fLongitude').innerHTML = <?=$fqlResult[0]['longitude']?>;

//Output
No. of Facebook Checkins: 
Latitude: 
Longitude:
```

*JavaScript Setup 2* (No blockage - Okay)

```
document.getElementById('fLatitude').innerHTML = <?=$fqlResult[0]['latitude']?>;
document.getElementById('fLongitude').innerHTML = <?=$fqlResult[0]['longitude']?>;

//Output
No. of Facebook Checkins: 
Latitude: 1.2894680406278
Longitude: 103.86311775635
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latitude and logitude are numbers, so no problem there.

But *name* is a string (a.k.a. text literal), and *what* did you forget to put around the value in your JavaScript code …? Exactly, **string delimiters**.

You should really learn how to work with your browser’s error console …!